# Array of tokens

Tags: python, class, methods

I was following the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eythq9848Fg&list=PLZQftyCk7_SdoVexSmwy_tBgs7P0b97yD&index=1)

```
TT_INT = 'INT'
TT_FLOAT = 'FLOAT'
TT_PLUS = 'PLUS'
TT_MINUS = 'MINUS'
TT_MUL = 'MUL'
TT_DIV = 'DIV'
TT_LPAREN = 'LPAREN'
TT_RPAREN = 'RPAREN'

####################################
# TOKEN
####################################

class Token:
    def __init__(self, type_, value=None):
        self.type = type_
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.value: return f'{self.type}:{self.value}'
        return f'{self.type}'
```

He was calling `Token` like this

```
Token[TT_DIV]
```

I got an error. He initialized a class called Token. He declared twice variable `type_` and `value`. Then, in `__repr__` method he checked if `value` (Actually it is like checking boolean. But, value isn't boolean. So, what is that? What is happening write here. And, I know it will always return true) Then, he returned `type:value`. Then, `type`. Now, the my question is class `Token` isn't returning any type of array. So, why he is calling `Token` by `Token[TT_DIV]`(or something else). It is outta my mind.

I could directly use `TT_DIV` or something else to call that `value`. But, I want to know why he did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss-read what was in the video. Class instantiation is similar to a function call `f(x)` in terms of syntax. This is because 'calling' a class is equivalent to calling its `__init__` function which creates an instance of the class as an object.

Try this -

```
Token(TT_DIV)
```

```
DIV
```

---

Checked the video for an instance of the same:

[image]

---

Try this -

```
a = Token(TT_DIV)
b = Token(TT_FLOAT)

print(a.__dict__, b.__dict__)
```

`object.__dict__` gives you the self dictionary where you are storing everything.

Comment: hmm! you got it. But, I am unable to accept the answer before 10 minutes

Comment: No worries :) happy to help

Comment: Does it actually mean I am sending the `TT_DIV` value to that `init` function. Then, it is initializing  that value in `type`.
Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: Think of a init method as the function that gets called by default when you "call" a class. Its job is to instantiate the class and create an object. The variables that you create get stored in the `object.self` dictionary.

Comment: I  have updated the answer to give more details. I like to imagine a class as a database that stores keys and values in something called 'self'. each time you instantiate a class into an object, you are calling the `__init__` function which initializes a dictionary called `self` that stores all the variables you define in the class. You also store multiple functions which modify this `self` dict. That is why all functions take `self` as a paramter. It lets them share data across functions via common dictionary. You can see the `self` by `object.__dict__`.

Comment: Hope that clarifies what you are trying to do.